# If $f'$ is bounded, what can be said about $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I came across this question in order to solve another problem: "If $|f'(x)|\leq M$, what can be said about $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$?

I made an attempt to answer it, here it is:

By the mean value theorem, for every $(a,\infty)$ exists $c_x\in(a,x)$ such that:

$|f(x)|=|f(a)+f(c_x)(x-a)|\leq |f(a)+M(x-a)|$. Since $(x-a)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, it follows that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$.

Is it correct?

Comment: That shows that the limit is bounded above by $\infty$, which doesn't help much.

Comment: No.  Take $f(x)=\sin(x)$ for example.  Or a constant $f(x)$ for that matter.

Comment: does it guarantee that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is finite, or at least bounded?

Comment: It doesn't guarantee anything.  Consider $f(x) = x$.  $f'$ is bounded and even constant but it diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 5):

It tells you the  function is $\mathcal O(x)$ which imo is useful.

To see this notice that if $|f'(t)|\leq M$ for all $t$ then for positive $x$:

$|f(x)|=|\int\limits_0^x f'(t)dt+f(0)|\leq \int\limits_0^x |f'(t)|dt+|f(0)|\leq \int\limits_{0}^x Mdt+|f(0)|\leq Mx+|f(0)|$

Comment: $f'$ need not be Riemann integrable